# Good sources for elementary QFT exercises

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education, scattering-cross-section

Most standard QFT textbooks have plenty of exercises, ranging from basic to challenging, to reinforce the theory discussed. However what I'm sorely lacking is some experience in doing the elementary, Wick contractions-based exercises of the form 'given *this* interaction Lagrangian, evaluate for *this* process the probablity amplitude (to first non-null order and strictly without loops) and the cross section/ decay width'.

Some examples of what I mean:

1. (Higgs boson decay). Given the process $h\to e^+ e^-$ described by $\mathcal L_I=-gh(x)\bar\psi(x)\psi(x)$, calculate $A$ and $\Gamma$;
2. (Pion-pion scattering). Given the process $\pi^++\pi^0\to \pi^++\pi^0$ with $\mathcal L_I=\lambda\partial_\mu\pi^0(x)\partial^\mu\pi^0(x)\pi^*(x)\pi(x)$, find $a$ and $d\sigma$;
3. Any other process inolving Lagrangians such as the QED Lagrangian $\mathcal L_I=-e\bar\psi(x)\gamma^\mu\psi(x)A_\mu$ or the phenomenological Lagrangian $\mathcal L_I=g_0\pi^0(x)\partial_\mu A_\nu(x) \partial_\sigma A_\lambda(x)\epsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}$.

Can anyone recommend to me a good source of such exercises?

Comment: Seems to me that your are perfectly able to formulate such exercises, but what you are really after is solutions?

Comment: @Oбжорoв Yes, exactly. it would be nice to have at the very least a final answer available or even a more detailed solution.